# How to pass outputs of two celery tasks in a chain to the third task?

Tags: python, django, celery

I am a beginner in Django and Celery and I'm trying to chain three tasks as follows:

`tasks = chain(task_analyze1, task_analyze2, task_combined)`

where I do further processing on outputs of `task_analyze1` and `task_analyze2` inside `task_combined`.

But so far from what I have read online, it seems that in `chain`, the output of one task is passed to the next task, so I will only get the output of `task_analyze2` in `task_combined`.

Is there a way, either by using chain or maybe some other way, to get the output of both tasks?

**Edit**:

One possible way around it that comes to mind is to include the output of first task in the output of second task as well. But since the second task in my case is being used in a few other places, changing it would break a lot of other things in my code.

I was interested to know whether Celery chain has a dynamic inside it that would allow the outputs to pass further in chain and not only to the immediate task following them.

Comment: Does `task_analyze2` depend on the output of `task_analyze1`?

Comment: I think what @tzaman is getting at is it's usually easier to pass the arguments through the function then to sit there and wait for a task to return to do a `.get()`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually `task_analyze2` does depend on `task_analyze1` and `task_combined` depends on both of them. I'm also not sure if I understand what you mean by passing the arguments through the function.